# how can i check with arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have a problem: I want to create a small game, I have to make a window like the following:

[image]

The program makes sure that the words come from the word list and are ordered in correct dictionary order ..

so , i was stored the words in Array list

when i tried to check if the words from Array list or not , the code it's not work with me ( j1.getText().equals(a1) && j2.getText().equals(a1) ) ..

firstly i want check if the words come from array list or not , just :((

Thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent ; 
import java.util.ArrayList ;

public class GameWords extends JFrame 

{
private static final int W = 800 ;
private static final int H = 600 ;
private JLabel heading  ;
private JLabel h1 ;
private JLabel h2 ;
private JButton b1 ;
private JButton b2 ;
private JTextField j1 ;
private JTextField j2 ;
ArrayList < String > a1 = new ArrayList < String > (30) ;
public void a1 ()
{

      a1.add("dog") ;
      a1.add("eat") ;
      a1.add("snout");
      a1.add("lonely");
      a1.add("zeal");
      a1.add("bike");
      a1.add("tree");
      a1.add("dogma");
      a1.add("pig");
      a1.add("desk");
      a1.add("zoo");
      a1.add("dirt");
      a1.add("ball");
      a1.add("troglodyte");
      a1.add("man");
      a1.add("treason");
      a1.add("my");
      a1.add("smile");
      a1.add("cat");
      a1.add("cowboy");
      a1.add("woman");
      a1.add("supercilious");
      a1.add("do");
      a1.add("mom");
      a1.add("cow");
      a1.add("ice");
      a1.add("log");
      a1.add("suber");
      a1.add("scant");
      a1.add("nose") ;

}


public GameWords ()
{
     setTitle ( " Word Order Game " ) ;
     setLayout ( new FlowLayout() ) ;
     setDefaultCloseOperation ( EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) ;
     createContent () ;
     pack();
     setVisible ( true ) ;
}

public void createContent ()
{
     heading = new JLabel () ;
     h1 = new JLabel () ;
     h2 = new JLabel () ;
     b1 = new JButton ( " Submit " ) ;
     b2 = new JButton ( " Clear " ) ;
     j1 = new JTextField ( 10 ) ;
     j2 = new JTextField ( 10 ) ;
      heading.setText( " Fun with words " ) ;
      heading.setFont ( heading.getFont().deriveFont ( 26f )) ; 
      heading.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 300, 4 * 190 ));
    h1.setText( " Hey Kids! Want to prictice your typing and word-
 ordering Skills ? ") ;
    h2.setText( " pick two words from the following list, enter them in 
 the boxes in the correct order and then press the Submit Button ");

    add ( heading ) ;
    add ( h1 ) ;
    add ( h2 ) ;
    add ( b1 ) ;
    add ( b2 ) ;
    add ( j1 ) ;
    add ( j2 ) ;

    b1.addActionListener( new Listener() );
    b2.addActionListener( new Listener() );


}

    public class Listener implements ActionListener
    {

      public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
      {


          if ( e.getSource() == b1 )
          {
            if ( j1.getText().equals(a1) && j2.getText().equals(a1) ) 
            {
                h2.setText(" Your correct ");

            }
            else
            {
                h2.setText( " Worng ");

            }
          }
          else 
          {
              j1.setText("");
              j2.setText("");
          }

      }



    }

public static void main(String[] args) 

{
    new GameWords () ;

}
```

}

Comment: I think you are looking for the List method contains: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: And how can we know witch line is line 105?

Comment: @Guy just count them ;)

Comment: As a sidenode: You never seem to call your method `a1()` which initializes your list. So your List is most likely empty anyway.

Comment: @Guy , rptmat57 , Sorry, I modify the sentence now

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Pujari is correct.

You can not use a1 because it represent whole ArrayList.

You may iterate as Pujari said, or you can find items in ArrayList and compare their indexes

```
if (a1.indexOf(j1.getText()) <= a1.indexOf(j2.getText()) {
 h2.setText(" Your correct ");
}
else {
h2.setText( " Worng ");
}
```

You may either convert all text to lowercase or may use ignore case.

Regards,
Krishan

Comment: careful that indexOf will return -1 if the supplied argument is not found. So your if statement will also return true if nothing is found (Because -1 <= -1)

Answer (score 0):

> Where are you calling your `a1()` Method

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e ){
          if ( e.getSource() == b1 ){
            if ( j1.getText().equals(a1) && j2.getText().equals(a1) ){
                h2.setText(" Your correct ");
            }else{
                h2.setText( " Worng ");

            }
          }else{
              j1.setText("");
              j2.setText("");
          }
       }
    }
```

Here in the above code will not work, you cannot just write `a1` You need to iterate through it so you need to do something like this

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e ){
          if ( e.getSource() == b1 ){
            for(String arrayListItem : a1){
              if (j1.getText().equals(arrayListItem) && j2.getText().equals(arrayListItem)){
                h2.setText(" Your correct ");
              }else{
                h2.setText( " Worng ");
              }
            }
          }else{
              j1.setText("");
              j2.setText("");
          }
       }
    }
```

Please change the name of the method `a1()` to something else as its confusing with `ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList.indexOf() which gives you the position of the element in the List.Then you can compare the 2 indexes to see if one comes before the other.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

```
This method returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.
```

Answer (score 0):

If i may give you a tip for initializing ArrayLists i would say using a textFile and BufferedReader is a way more clean and effecient way. You basicly fill each line in a textFile with a word and then use this piece of code

```
File file = new File("myFile");
ArrayList <String> myText = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String line;

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        myText.add(line);
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will make it so that you can easily fill a large arrayList of words without having to type in every single .add()